# Google drive lacking pause funcntionality

Tags: google-drive

Many a times while uploading files of size up to few gigabytes it is not possible to do that in one go. So is there any pause function? Or the only way is to download the google drive desktop app and start syncing all the files.

Another issue is that when I copy the files from its original directory to google drive folder to copies of the same file is saved. I can move it but then I don't want to encounter the hassle of accessing every files from the drive folder. On top of that it start syncing each and every file, that requires a lot of time.

Last night I planned of syncing it overnight only to get up at morning to find that google drive has lost connection. Although the internet connection was all right it didn't try to reconnect back as a result only 200 mb of my 5 gb files got uploaded all through the night. Quite frustrating.

I am new to drive so I need help with these issues I think I am missing out with something.

Comment: Since you're asking about the Drive sync tool and not the Web app, this question should be on [su].

Comment: I am new to this site so can you please clarify?

Comment: Start by reading the detailed information on the [tag:google-drive] tag.